# Encoding 8 bit wav in javascript using Matt Diamond's recorder.js

Tags: javascript, audio

I made a javascript audio recorder that records audio files and stores in on server. For that, I used the code from this example: https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html.

It records 16 bit wav files, and it works flawlessly both in chrome and firefox. However, I need it to record 8 bit wav files.

I made the following changes in recorderworker.js:

1) I changed the encodeWav function so that in the header of a wav file there is info it's a 8 bit file, not 16 bit:

```
function encodeWAV(samples, mono){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* RIFF identifier */
  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  /* file length */
  view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
  /* RIFF type */
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  /* format chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  /* format chunk length */
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  /* sample format (raw) */
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  /* channel count */
  view.setUint16(22, mono?1:2, true);
  /* sample rate */
  view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
  /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
  view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
  /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
  /* bits per sample */
  view.setUint16(34, 8, true);
  /* data chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  /* data chunk length */
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

  floatTo8BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}
```

2) I made a function floatTo8BitPCM to replace floatTo16BitPCM and it looks like this:

```
function floatTo8BitPCM(output, offset, input){
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset++){
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    output.setInt8(offset, (s * 128) + 128);
  }
}
```

When I record the sound, it always works in chrome but only sometimes in firefox. And, also the resulting file is two times longer than it should be. The first half is what I recorded and the second half is silent.

I tried setting the buffer size to 44 + sample.length instead of 44 + sample.length * 2, and setting the file length to 32 + sample.length instead of 32 + sample.length * 2.

Edit: Also, when I reduced the file size and buffer size as I mentioned, the file stayed 2 times longer when I play it in itunes, but when I play it in browser it's 2 times shorter and I hear just the first half of it.

Comment: Your data chunk size, the file size, the `byte rate`, the `BlockAlign`,  should depend on `mono` also, not only the `channel count`.

Answer (score 2):

the sample size for 8-bit is just that, 8-bits. It is embedded in the block alignment, byte rate and bits per sample. You also need to pay more attention to the channel count if you are supporting both mono and stereo.

```
int bytesPerSample = 1;
int channelCount = mono ? 2 : 1;
int blockAlign =  bytesPerSample * channelCount;
int bitsPerSample = bytesPerSample * 8;

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length*blockAlign);
...
/* channel count */
view.setUint16(22, channelCount, true);
/* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
view.setUint32(28, sampleRate*blockAlign, true);
/* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
view.setUint16(32, blockAlign, true);
/* bits per sample */
view.setUint16(34, bitsPerSample, true);
...
/* data chunk length */
view.setUint32(40, samples.length*blockAlign, true);
```

As a side note, your conversion from float to byte has the possibility of overflowing.  Consider that at the maximum float sample value can be 1.0 then by your formula that would convert to 256 which is too big.

```
 1.0 * 128 + 128 = 256 
-1.0 * 128 + 128 = 0
```

You need to choose between one of the following. I don't know if there is a standard defining which is correct:

```
 1.0 * 127 + 128 = 255
-1.0 * 127 + 128 = 1

 1.0 * 127 + 127 = 254
-1.0 * 127 + 127 = 0
```